# Javascript - Create deep object from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I need to create an object from an array.

For example,

I have a array like `var arr = ['a', 'b', 'c'];`

it should be converted to,

```
{
  a:{
    b:{
      c:{
      
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I tried the below code but not able to create a deep tree,

```
var arr = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
var obj = {},
    temp = 'asd';
for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
    if($.isEmptyObject(obj)){
        obj[arr[i]] = {};
    } else {
        console.log(Object.keys(obj));
        obj[Object.keys(obj)][arr[i]] = {};
    }
}
console.log(obj, temp);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aravindtrue/6p4c8vcb/1/)

Can someone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try something like

```js
var arr = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
var obj = temp = {};
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  temp = temp[arr[i]] = {}
}

$('#result').html(JSON.stringify(obj))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result"></div>
```